# Java 8: Converting an array of strings to have first character in uppercase and sorted order

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a array of string like:

```
String[] strArray = { "Red", "green", "Blue", "Yellow", "violet", "magenta", "pURPLE" };
```

I want this to convert it into an array such that all strings in the given array has first character in uppercase. Expected output should be:

```
[Blue, Green, Magenta, PURPLE, Red, Violet, Yellow]
```

Finally the array should be sorted(this one is easy just adding `sorted()` operation).

I am trying this but its not working:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(strArray)
                .map((String x) -> {x=(x != null ? (x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1, x.length())) : "");})
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The method map(Function<? super String,? extends R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments ((String x) -> {})
```

I'm sure I'm missing some small thing but I am not able to figure out what.

Comment: A simple typographical error. The lambda expression must `return` a value, not assign a value to the parameter. So instead of `.map((String x) -> {x=(…);})`, you have to write `.map((String x) -> { return (…);})`, or use the short form `.map(x -> (…))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Character.toUpperCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) method for this.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(strArray)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(s->Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))+ s.substring(1))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: you don't need the Comparator in the sorted() method here, as the default does the same as `Comparator.comparing(s->s))`

Comment: `Character.toUpperCase` returns char. I'm assuming this gets converted to string due to `s.substring`?

Comment: Pretty simple solution.

Comment: If you have `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`, then map call becomes more simple as `map(StringUtils::capitalize)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the new string in the method in map() - the x s the input value and you have to provide a mapped value:

```
    String[] strArray = { "Red", "green", "Blue", "Yellow", "violet", "magenta", "pURPLE" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(strArray)
            .map((String x) -> { return (x != null ? (x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1, x.length())) : "");})
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

a little shorter:

```
    String[] strArray = { "Red", "green", "Blue", "Yellow", "violet", "magenta", "pURPLE" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(strArray)
            .map(x -> x != null ? (x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1, x.length())) : "")
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the said compilation error because you've decided to use a *lambda statement block* for the `map` function and decided not to include a `return` statement.

The `map` function transforms an element of type `T` to `R`, so if you decide to use a *lambda statement block* you'll need to provide a `return` statement *explicitly*, the only case in which you don't need to provide an explicit return statement is if you use a *lambda expression*.

The other answers show how to accomplish the task at hand using streams. another variant without streams would be:

```
//copy the array of strings to a list of strings
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strArray));
// remove null
stringList.removeIf(Objects::isNull); 
// do replacing
stringList.replaceAll(s -> Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) ? 
            s : Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))+ s.substring(1));
// sort the list
tempList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```